# Lightweight code analysis tool for Java

Tags: gratis, java, code-analysis

I want a tool for a quick analysis scan of my source code.

My problem is that currently we use [SonarQube](http://www.sonarqube.org) but this thing is too fat to be used locally and it's now configured to run only in a certain branch and after a commit.

I want a tool to **quickly generate a report locally**, fix issues and then push the code to SonarQube for a final quality test.

When searching I found [this](http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/developers-guide-static-code-analysis-findbugs-checkstyle-pmd-coverity-sonarqube/2/) post, it mentions some tools but I have no idea what fits my requirements.

To sum up, a tool for:

- Code analysis in Java.
- To be installed locally(Main os Vista/7 although not a problem if it's a webapp for Tomcat or Wildfly).
- **Lightweight and fast** extra extra bold here :).
- I am not currently interested in test-coverage but it will be nice to support this too.
- Gratis, will be nice if it's open-source too.
- Easy configuration.

Comment: "Lightweight" and "fast" are not good descriptive terms, and answer responding to those terms will be *just* opinion, and SR isn't about opinions.  You also aren't clear on what you are willing to trade away; all that "heavyweight" stuff is presumably doing something useful.  Otherwise you'd be satisifed with the "lightweight" empty set of tools you are running "locally" now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jetbrains the makes or the IntelliJ IDE have a [code analysis](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/code-inspection.html) tool for Java.  It comes bundled with both there Community and Ultimate editions of IntelliJ.

- Seems to be pretty fast usually runs while you are using there IDE
- Can be run from [Command Lines](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/running-inspections-offline.html)
- Java Code
- There ide does Test coverage but I'm not sure you can use it outside of their IDE.
- Community Edition of IDE is free.
- I have run the Command line version and didn't find it to be that hard.

Comment: It was a shock when I first encountered it, coming from Eclipse, very very helpful! Only thing is that it analyzes opened IntelliJ projects but that's expected.